# Magento how to add extra fields for static block

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I've been trying to add extra fields to the static block so it will be easier to update.

How can I add a simple textfield or maybe a image upload field?

See example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HtDC.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to overwrite this class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Edit_Form`. This class is used to add fieldsets and fields for `cms_block`. Take a look on the `_prepareForm()` method inside it.

If you put this code, just after `Title` field,

```
    $fieldset->addField('sub_title', 'text', array(
        'name'      => 'sub_title',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Sub Title'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Sub Title'),
        'required'  => true,
    ));
```

you can see your `sub-title` text field in static blocks. However **Do not edit a core file directly**. You need to write a custom module that should overwrite this class. Your Module config file should contain this code

File : `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<config> 
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                     <cms_block_edit_form>Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Cms_Block_Edit_Form</cms_block_edit_form>
                </rewrite>        
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

This will allow you to rewrite the class. What you need to do now is define the rewrite class now and in there you need to rewrite `_prepareForm()`. It should some what look like this.

Location :  `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Cms/Block/Edit/Form.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Cms_Block_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Edit_Form {

     protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        //put all the code inside parent class here 
        //then place the below content in appropriate place

        $fieldset->addField('sub_title', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'sub_title',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Sub Title'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Sub Title'),
            'required'  => true,
        ));
        return parent::_prepareForm();

    }
}
```

Try based on this idea

### EDIT

Please note, it will allow you to put new field in `cms > block`, howver to save this, you need to define model for your module. You have two options. Add a new field to save your new field in Cms > Block table or create your own table and store this value in that field along with the referene to cms >block table. This is out of box  and you should implement it your own way.

Happy coding

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried to add it in a module but I get this error : 
`Fatal error: Call to a member function addField() on a non-object in C:\Git\abs\app\code\local\ShopCommerce\Static\Block\Adminhtml\Cms\Block\Edit\Form.php on line 8`

Comment: I added after the `parent::_prepareForm();` the following : `$form = new Varien_Data_Form(
            array('id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post')
        );

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('block_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('General Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide'));
`
Error is gone but my field isnt showing up.

Comment: I said it is hint to answer. It will direct you the right path. The first error will obviously happen, since `$fieldset` is not defined there. Good to know you tried something else. Did that worked for you ?

Comment: The `$fieldset` is now defined as `$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('General Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide'));`

I get no error now but my field Sub-title isnt showing.
When I add `$form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);` in the end, Sub-title field is the only thing I see. Its not adding to the other fields.

Comment: you don't need to struggle more. What you need to now is, copy all the codes inside `_prepareForm()`  in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Edit_Form` to your `_prepareForm()` and add your field there. That will do the trick

Comment: That was exactly what i did haha. The next problem is that it doenst save my value of the Sub-title field.

Comment: see my edit. In order to save data.. you need to create a new table or atleast update cms > block table according to your need. It is out of box question. You can do it. Just make a try

Comment: I've been trying to get it working, but I can't. It wont save my data. You got anymore tips?

Comment: try this http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/04/creating-a-magento-custom-model/ there are lot of tuts out there. Ask to google. She will not desperate you

Comment: You do not need to copy all the code in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Edit_Form::_prepareForm(). You can catch that output in a variable by calling parent::_prepareForm() from your own class, then manipulate that form object before you finally return it.

Answer (score 1):

In adition to @Rajeev
You need get the parent form in this way...

```
<?php
    class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Cms_Block_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Edit_Form {

         protected function _prepareForm()
        {
          $form = parent::_prepareForm()->getForm();
          $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('fieldset_example', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('core')->__('My example fieldset')));
          $fieldset->addField('sub_title', 'text', array(
                'name'      => 'sub_title',
                'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Sub Title'),
                'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Sub Title'),
                'required'  => true,
            ));
            return $this;    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is, rather add an extra field, you can add a `<div>...</div>` to in the content are by removing what you see is what you get editor(just click on the show / hide Editor).
And for image you can direct upload images by clicking on the `inset/edit image` option from the menu.
It will be simpler than creating custom fields.